# "reach a low of" and "reach a peak of"

Tags: prepositions

I have a question relates to the using of "reach a low of" and "reach a peak of".

Can we use a percentage after both of these sentences?

Or we need to change the preposition?

I know we can say "In 2005 the production of steel reached a low of 100 Kg"

Let's say that in that year the 100 Kg is presented 5% of the production capacity.

Can we say then "In 2005 the production of steel reached a low **of** 5%"?

Or we should say "In 2005 the production of steel reached a low **at** 5%"?

Comment: Certainly. You could also used "minimum" or "maximum'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we use a percentage after both of these sentences?

Yes. "Percentage" can be used like "amount" and "number".

> In 2005 the production of steel reached a low **of** 5%.

This is grammatically correct. We often use "a low of" and "a peak of".

> In 2005 the production of steel reached a low at 5%.

This means the same as the above (of), but less common.

As @DrMoishe_Pippik commented, you can also use "a minimum/maximum of" instead of "a low/peak of"